# filling a 2D numpy array in a pythonic way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

I am trying to populate a 2D numpy array.
In my experience, the following is not going to scale up well with array sizes.

```
x=np.array([2,3,4])
y=np.array([1,3,9,13])
mat=np.zeros((x.size,y.size))
for i in range(nx):
 for j in range(ny):
   if x[i] > y[j]:
        mat[i,j] = 1
   else:
        mat[i,j] = -1
```

Ideally, I would like to use list comprehension like
It would be simple if it was 1D only

```
mat=np.asarray([foo(x_) for x_ in x])
```

but how to generalize this to 2D np.arrays?
Other `numpy` based solutions are also suitable, but efficiency is the key metric here

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution or specifically like in the example to populate triangular parts of the matrix?

Comment: my application case is the one of the example. However, a general solution would be probably useful to more SO users... It would be nice to have something which works with a generic foo(x_,y_) with two inputs similarly to the last code line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mat`:

```
In [352]: mat
Out[352]: 
array([[ 1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1., -1., -1.]])
```

broadcasting `x` against `y`:

```
In [353]: x[:,None]>y
Out[353]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

turn that boolean mask into 1/-1 array with `where`:

```
In [354]: np.where(x[:,None]>y,1,-1)
Out[354]: 
array([[ 1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 1,  1, -1, -1]])
```

Or you could turn the boolean into a 0/1 array, and scale that to fit

```
(x[:,None]>y).astype(float)*2-1
```

A double loop over two 1d arrays or lists can often be cast as an `outer` operation like this.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to build 2 dimensional nested list comprehensions:

```
mat = np.array([[1 if x_ > y_ else -1 for y_ in y] for x_ in x])
```

However, this can become pretty unreadable, and is not much different from for loops as far performance scaling is concerned. [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and vectorization will usually work better with larger arrays:

```
mat = (x[:, None] > y[None, :]) * 2 - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
x=np.array([2,3,4])
y=np.array([1,3,9,13])
a = (x.reshape(x.shape[0], 1) - y) > 0  # a=(x.reshape(-1, 1) - y) > 0
a = a.astype(int)*2 -1
```

Comment: You can also pass `-1` to reshape instead of `x.shape[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

If using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
nx = x.size
ny = y.size
mat = np.sign(x * np.atleast_2d(np.ones(ny)).T - np.ones(nx) * np.atleast_2d(y).T)
mat[np.where(mat==0)] = -1
```

numpy will take care regarding efficiency (whatever it means here).

Comment: in the end, you answer (without the last line) was the solution to my actual problem. However, since I made a mistake in the question by describing incorrectly the desired behavior with when x==y, I cannot accept it. but thanks :)